# auto-generated sources and cmake configuration: developer build vs user build

Tags: cmake, packaging

This question is about setting up CMake configuration files so as to serve plain users as well as co-developers.

Both user groups will need to *compile*. The difference between them is that co-developers, before compiling, will run a number of code generators or converters like `flex/bison`, `swig` or `pod2man`. These tools shall not be provided with our source package, but be required as external dependences. Plain users, however, shall be provided with all auto-generated code so that they do not need to install and run any tool other than cmake, make, and a compiler.

Now the question: How to set up the main `CMakeLists.txt` so that upon `cmake` we just compile, whereas upon `cmake <expert flag>` all auxiliary tools are required and run? As an obvious refinement, more fine-grained flags should allow to switch single tools on or off.

Comment: If you are not planning to distribute the code generators or converters with the source package for "plain users", you could use that as a differentiator. Just check for the existence of the tools or their subdirectories. The main question would be how you deliver the output of the code generators or converters (which normally end-up in the binary output directories for "co-developers")? To not have duplicate files (delivered and generated), you could add the outputs as Zip and extract it into the binary output during build environment generation.

Comment: @Florian: People should be free to change roles between user and developer; presence of tools should not automatically trigger their use. In the second part of your comment you raise an important issue: which directory should hold the auto-generated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As easy as

```
option(DEVELOPER_MODE "This will run developer tools during build" OFF)

...

if(DEVELOPER_MODE)
 add targets for flex and stuff
endif()
```

Now configure your build with `cmake -D DEVELOPER_MODE=YES ..` to enable it.

Comment: Thank you. I accept since my question was not clear enough to expect a more detailed answer. I still do not see clearly how to organize source vs build directories, since auto-generated files are source for a user, but belong into `build` for a developer. I'll probably ask a separate question about that.

Comment: When generating these files you can use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/out.file` as output file name.